# Git sign a tag / commit otherthan gpg

Tags: git, git-sign

In Git, can we use Entrust Digital SW to sign tags and commits instead of gpg?

need your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `git tag -s` and `git tag -v` allow any key but GPG (but I could be wrong). From the man page:

```
-s, --sign
    Make a GPG-signed tag, using the default e-mail address's key. 

-v, --verify
    Verify the gpg signature of the given tag names.
```

That written, annotated tags, i.e. those generated with `git tag -a <tagname>` allow arbitrary messages, much like commits. There's no reason you couldn't paste your keys into the message, and then your upstream maintainers (or whomever's doing the checks) could just manually verify the key. You can get at the message with `git show <tag>`, and it shouldn't be difficult to script the verification.